Why is aws cdk failing to synth and throwing "[ERROR] Could not resolve [package]"?
This project is a year in and 3 devs on the team are using it. Until today, never had a problem building and deploying it. I recently moved over from my Mac to a Debian desktop and cloned the project. This is the only instance where it throws the error:
Bundling asset MyProject/IngestionStagingLambda/Code/Stage...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "jsonstream"

    lambda/service/IngestionService.ts:4:28:
      4 │ import * as JSONStream from "jsonstream";
        ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~

I've tried putting JSONStream in the Lambda's externalModules in bundling like so, but it doesn't change anything:
this.ingestionStagingLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "IngestionStagingLambda", {
    functionName: "ingestionStagingHandler",
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
    handler: "ingestionStagingHandler",
    entry: "./lambda/ingestionStagingHandler.ts",
    memorySize: 256,
    timeout: Duration.minutes(5),
    bundling: {
        minify: true,
        externalModules: [
            "JSONStream"
        ]
    }
});

It may look strange due to the casing, but the typedef is lowercase - here's package.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonstream": "^0.8.33",
    ...
},
"dependencies": {
    "JSONStream": "^1.3.5",
    ....
}

I've tried matching the same cdk version and all package versions in the project, to what is configured on the version on my Mac. There aren't any indications of problems anywhere with TS or anything else. No one else can reproduce it.

The package is named JSONStream but you are importing jsonstream. Maybe the problem comes from a case-(in)sensitive file-system. How does dependency look like in the package.json?

@SAE That's due to the TS typedef, which is lowercase. It's lowercase in package.json and like I mentioned - it builds and deploys on all other machines, as-is.

Ok - thought you want to use the package - not the types - in IngestionService.ts

@SAE I don't follow. It's a TS project and I need the types, and there hasn't been an issue until moving to a new machine. What am I doing wrong here?

The types are just the types - you don't need them to import unless you want to actually use them, e.g. as typing for variables/functions. If you want to use the functions from JSONStream, you'll have to import the package - not the types.

@SAE Right, I get that - and cdk synth works if I use the correct casing (no typedef) - but then I'm left with a TS build error in the files where I make reference to the package.
Could not find a declaration file for module 'JSONStream'. '/my_project/node_modules/JSONStream/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try npm i --save-dev @types/JSONStream if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'JSONStream';
...which doesn't exist, because uppercase package names are no longer allowed. Hence the lowercase option installed. How do I get around TS?

@types/JSONStream as the typing package for JSONStream may not work on case-insensitive OSes, because then the built-in fallback to lower-cased package names is not able to resolve the name.
You should be able to work around the issue with a package alias:
npm i @types/JSONStream@npm:@types/jsonstream

(Source)
